# error "No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page" Delphi 11 using TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode

Tags: encoding, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I know that is a common problem but i heaven't found any solution.
I have an event that encode a string

```
'MyPassword123!' := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(edPassword.Text);
```

i need to decode this string

```
s :=  TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(edPassword.text);
```

using VCL it all works fine but using FireMonkey it gives me the error

```
No mapping for unicode character exists in target multi-byte code page
```

at runtime. I can not understand why so i'm not able to solve this problem. Can yuo please help me?

sorry the example is very minimal nut i hope it will be clear enough.
thank you

EDIT
i heaven't thougt it was so complicated to explain so this is a complete example:
i have three edit i would like to encode a string and then redecode the encoded one

```
const salt : UTF8String = 'SECRET';

procedure Tfmmain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
    Edit2.Text := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode(salt+Edit1.Text);
 end;


procedure Tfmmain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   s : string;
begin
   s := TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(Edit2.Text);
   edit3.Text := StringReplace(s,salt,'',[]);
end;
```

in VCL works fine but the same code under Firemonkey does not.
thank you in advance.

Comment: What values are in `salt` and `edPassword.Text` during encoding? What is the output?  What value is in `edPassword.Text` (shouldn't that be `edCriptata`?) during decoding? `Base64.Encode()` converts the input `string` to UTF-8 bytes and then encodes the bytes as base64. `Base64.Decode()` decodes the input base64 string to bytes and then decodes the bytes as UTF-8. Are you sure you are proving the correct base64 input string that represents UTF-8 bytes? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes sorry i'll update my question

Comment: Your edit wasn't very helpful. So, lets try something simpler. Does this fail for you? `TNetEncoding.Base64.Decode(TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode('MyPassword123!'))`

Comment: No it doesn't it works well. I have put a full example code i hope clearer.

Comment: If the statement I gave you doesn't work then you need to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero. That is the root of your problem. Also, why is your `salt` a `UTF8String`? You are using it in `UnicodeString` operations, so it will always have to be converted to a `UnicodeString` at runtime. That is unnecessary overhead. Also, why `StringReplace()`? You should verify the decoded string begins with the `salt` and then simply `Delete()` or `Copy()` it off of the string. No need to search the string.